# bash script does not execute lines after sudo, no errors

Tags: bash, ptpd

I have a little bash script to run, but it appears to stop without errors on the second line:

```
export REQUIRE_TRIGGER=0
sudo -s -H
killall ptpd ntpd
nice -n -19 ptpd -gGW -b eth0 -s2 -i NTP -t -c D
```

The script is in a file. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that `killall` won't be run until `sudo` finishes and exits.

Comment: The script is inside a file.

Comment: Yes, you included the commands you want `sudo` to run in the file, but you didn't do anything to cause them to be fed to stdin of the shell `sudo` starts. So that shell is still trying to read from the script's original stdin, **not** reading the commands later in the script.

Comment: ...which is to say: `bash somescript` is **not at all** the same thing as `bash <somescript`. (Not that the latter is safe either: The shell is perfectly free to consume lines ahead of the one it's currently executing, and in many cases is *required* to do so, making that file content unavailable to other programs inheriting the FD).

Comment: (Adding the fact that "the script is in a file" to your question does not make this any less duplicative; the other answers still apply just as much as they did pre-edit).

Comment: What is the safe solution?

Comment: A heredoc, as described in the linked questions' answers, or to escalate each command individually, as your current answer suggests. Heredocs aren't safe *for passwords*, but if they're just containing script content, that's a very standard use.

Comment: (If you want to allow the current user to run those explicit commands without entering any password, you can put that configuration in `/etc/sudoers`).

Answer (score 1):

try to do

```
    sudo killall ptpd ntpd
    sudo nice -n -19 ptpd -gGW -b eth0 -s2 -i NTP -t -c D
```